# Filter and summarize table by multiple related conditions

Tags: powerbi, dax

Let's say I have 3 tables,
Table 1 is the parent information for table 2
Table 2 is the unpivoted information describing table 1
Table 3 is the filter condition

Example:
Table1:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | T1 |
| 2 | T2 |
| 3 | T3 |

Table2 (Table1[ID] <-> Table2[Parent ID]):

| ID | Parent ID | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Ca | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | Cb | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | Ca | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | Cb | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | Cc | 1 |
| 6 | 2 | Cd | 1 |
| 7 | 3 | Ca | 1 |
| 8 | 3 | Cb | 0 |

Table3:

| ID | Group | Name | Min Value | Max Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | G1 | Ca | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | G1 | Cb | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | G2 | Ca | 1 | null |
| 4 | G2 | Cb | 1 | null |
| 5 | G2 | Cc | 1 | 1 |

I would like to display in table for how many Parent meet the criteria, but I not sure how to link Table 2 and Table 3. Or does it no need to link, can just using measure?

**Sample outcome:**

| Group | Match Pattern |
| --- | --- |
| G1 | 2 |
| G2 | 1 |

Explanation:
So from the 3 tables, I should get the output where there are 2 parent satisfied the condition of G1 from Table 3, while only 1 parent satisfied the condition of G2.
For G1, Ca and Cb must be in between 1 and 2 inclusively. T1 and T2 fulfill the criteria, while T3 has Cb = 0. Thus answer is 2.
For G2, Ca and Cb must be >= 1, while Cc must be equal 1. Only T2 fulfill the criteria, T1 does not meet because missing Cc, T3 missing Cc and Cb = 0. Thus answer is 1.

---

I'm pretty beginner to this, so I might not try much. I don't think linking the Name in Table 3 and Name in Table 2 is right, so I didn't try that.
But I tried to create measure with COUNTX like below,

```
COUNTX(
    FILTER(
        Table2
        ,Table2[Name]=Table3[Name] 
          && 
          Table2[Value]>=Table3[Min Value] 
          && 
          Table2[Value]<=Table3[Max Value]
    )
   ,Table2[Parent ID]
)
```

, but all total match pattern I get is 0.

Comment: add a result sample.

Comment: @Mik Added in the question's body. Thanks.

Comment: I cant get the point from your explanation. So, please, make it more simple for understanding. may be step by step with some math

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a new **Observations** table from Table2 with an added Parent Name from Table1

```
Observations = 
SELECTCOLUMNS(
    Table2,
    "ParentName", RELATED('Table1'[Name]),
    "ObsParameter", Table2[Name],
    "Value", Table2[Value]
)
```

[image]

2. Create a new **Conditions** table from Table3 with a 999 Max Value instead of null

```
Conditions = 
SELECTCOLUMNS(
    Table3,
    "Group", Table3[Group],
    "CondParameter", Table3[Name],
    "Min", Table3[Min Value],
    "Max", IF(ISBLANK(Table3[Max Value]), 999, Table3[Max Value])
)
```

[image]

3. Crossjoin **Conditions** with **Observation**, filter matches and group by Group and Parent Name

```
Match = 
GROUPBY(
    FILTER(
        CROSSJOIN(Conditions, Observations),
        [CondParameter] = [ObsParameter]
        && [Min] <= [Value]
        && [Value] <= [Max] = TRUE()
    ),
    [Group],
    [ParentName],
    "Count", COUNTX(CURRENTGROUP(), [ParentName])
)
```

[image]

4. Summarize Table3 as ConditionCount to get the number of conditions per group and create a relation between 'ConditionCount'[Group] and 'Match'[Group]

```
ConditionCount = 
SUMMARIZE(
    Table3,
    Table3[Group],
    "NumConditions", COUNT(Table3[ID])
)
```

[image]

5. Filter on Match[Count] = NumConditions and group again to count the parents

```
Result = 
GROUPBY(
    FILTER(
        Match,
        Match[Count] = RELATED(ConditionCount[NumConditions])
    ),
    [Group],
    "Match Pattern", COUNTX(CURRENTGROUP(),[ParentName])
)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Peter. Sorry for responding late. It took some time for me to try it out, but it really helps me to understand how to use power bi. Thanks a lot!